# Adding color-dodge/divide blending mode in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl, fabricjs

Trying to create a new blending mode option for `color-dodge` (or `divide` both are very similar.)

current list of blending modes for webgl:

```
fragmentSource: {
  multiply: 'gl_FragColor.rgb *= uColor.rgb;\n',
  screen: 'gl_FragColor.rgb = 1.0 - (1.0 - gl_FragColor.rgb) * (1.0 - uColor.rgb);\n',
  add: 'gl_FragColor.rgb += uColor.rgb;\n',
  diff: 'gl_FragColor.rgb = abs(gl_FragColor.rgb - uColor.rgb);\n',
  subtract: 'gl_FragColor.rgb -= uColor.rgb;\n',
  lighten: 'gl_FragColor.rgb = max(gl_FragColor.rgb, uColor.rgb);\n',
  darken: 'gl_FragColor.rgb = min(gl_FragColor.rgb, uColor.rgb);\n',
  exclusion: 'gl_FragColor.rgb += uColor.rgb - 2.0 * (uColor.rgb * gl_FragColor.rgb);\n',
  overlay: 'if (uColor.r < 0.5) {\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.r *= 2.0 * uColor.r;\n' +
    '} else {\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.r = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - gl_FragColor.r) * (1.0 - uColor.r);\n' +
    '}\n' +
    'if (uColor.g < 0.5) {\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.g *= 2.0 * uColor.g;\n' +
    '} else {\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.g = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - gl_FragColor.g) * (1.0 - uColor.g);\n' +
    '}\n' +
    'if (uColor.b < 0.5) {\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.b *= 2.0 * uColor.b;\n' +
    '} else {\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.b = 1.0 - 2.0 * (1.0 - gl_FragColor.b) * (1.0 - uColor.b);\n' +
    '}\n',
  tint: 'gl_FragColor.rgb *= (1.0 - uColor.a);\n' +
    'gl_FragColor.rgb += uColor.rgb;\n',
},
```

according to resources i've read ([1](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Divide), [3](https://mouaif.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/photoshop-math-with-glsl-shaders/)), for `color-dodge` the math should be per channel and should be `min(1.0, baseColor / (1 - blendColor))`

i've tried to add an option for

```
divide: 'gl_FragColor.r = min(1.0, gl_FragColor.r / (1 - uColor.r));\n' +
        'gl_FragColor.g = min(1.0, gl_FragColor.g / (1 - uColor.g));\n' +
        'gl_FragColor.b = min(1.0, gl_FragColor.b / (1 - uColor.b));\n',
```

but the result image is always a different shade of the same blue no matter what color is passed in to be blended

here is how i'm applying the filter

```
var fabricImg = new fabric.Image(pageBackgroundImg), // make a fabric.Image object out of the HTMLImageElement
    blendedCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, {
        width: fabricImg.getScaledWidth(),
        height: fabricImg.getScaledHeight(),
        renderOnAddRemove: false
    }),
    pageBackgroundPattern;

// add the color filter to the image
fabricImg.filters.push(
    new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
        color: '#' + color,
        mode: 'divide'
    })
);
fabricImg.applyFilters();
// add the image to the canvas
blendedCanvas.add(fabricImg);

blendedCanvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: does the filter change the image in some way or it does not change at all?

Comment: I m also sure you can obtain the same effect with some vector math if a vector min exists.

Comment: The code looks good, i would expect it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i added a snippet so that we can understand better.
The filter you added IS doing something, if this is what should happen with a photoshop divide/colordodge, we can understand only comparing.
Your code is correct and is indeed working

Scroll down to compare original image with the filtered one

```js
function start() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  var image = document.getElementById('img');
  var fabricImg = new fabric.Image(image); 

  fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor.prototype.fragmentSource.divide =
  'gl_FragColor.r = min(1.0, gl_FragColor.r / (1.0 - uColor.r));\n' +
          'gl_FragColor.g = min(1.0, gl_FragColor.g / (1.0 - uColor.g));\n' +
          'gl_FragColor.b = min(1.0, gl_FragColor.b / (1.0 - uColor.b));\n';
  fabricImg.filters.push(
      new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
          color: '#0000ff',
          mode: 'divide'
      })
  );
  fabricImg.applyFilters();
  canvas.add(fabricImg);
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width=500 height=400 ></canvas>
<img crossOrigin="anonymous" onload="start()" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabricjs.com/gh-pages/assets/dragon2.jpg" id="img" />
```

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to look into this. i think my problem was the image i was trying to blend a color on. but you are correct, that filter does in fact work.

Comment: you should open a small pr to fabricjs contributing the code for webgl and canvas for it.